# Adding data to tableview in JavaFX gives every column identical values

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm having a problem where every single column in my table takes on the exact same value. More specifically, they all take on the value of what the second column should have.

However, the column names, themselves, are fine.

Let's say I have an `ObeservableList<ObservableList> data`

And I populate `data` so it looks like:

`[[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24],[31,32,33,34]]`

My table (java applet, but I just wrote the text down here) ends up looking like this:

```
Cat1|Cat2|Cat3|Cat4      when I want it to be:    Cat1|Cat2|Cat3|cat4
12  | 12 | 12 | 12                                11  | 12 | 13 | 14
22  | 22 | 22 | 22                                ....
32  | 32 | 32 | 32
...
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Here's the code for the tableview part

`System.out.println(data)
tableview.setItems(data)`

I thought that would be enough to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to every column a `CellValueFactory` that tells column, which value from nested `ObservableList` need to be shown.

example:

```
@FXML
private TableView<ObservableList> productsTable
@FXML
private TableColumn<ObservableList, String> column1
@FXML
private TableColumn<ObservableList, String> column2

...

    column1.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getAt(0).toString());
        }
    });
    column2.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getAt(1).toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! I had that inside a for loop and I had accidentally plugged in a 1 instead of an i, so instead of iterating over each element in the list it was just going over the second element.